# Apache2 auto-reloads every morning, then fails

Tags: apache2

Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie), Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64
Apache Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Apache2 on my server auto-reloads every morning (06:25). I see from other posts that this might be caused by logrotate, but I am not sure how/where to verify that. I'd expect that somewhere there's a cron job that is started daily at 06:25 that contains the commands for stopping and running Apache2 service. But I don't know where that config file is, would be nice to know.

But that's not the main problem. The main problem is that my server has started to fail after this reload. This morning there are the folloging messages in the sysctl log:

```
Jul 24 06:25:02 ip-172-30-0-106 apache2[28370]: Reloading web server: apache2 failed!
Jul 24 06:25:02 ip-172-30-0-106 apache2[28370]: Apache2 is not running ... (warning).
Jul 24 06:25:02 ip-172-30-0-106 systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

There's nothing on that time in Apache2 error log, though.

The tricky part is that if I run `$ service apache2 restart`, it restarts just fine without any errors. So I can not force the system to show what's wrong.

I wonder now how to investigate this situation. I will see if the auto-reload fails also next morning and update this post.

Comment: With Jessie (or any systemd-based OS) you'll want to be using `systemctl` for commands rather than "service", although I'm sure service maps to the appropriate systemd command anyway. I'd suggest looking at the unit file for apache2 and logrotate config to see what's going on. You should be able to reproduce the condition by sending the same command. `systemctl status apache2` gives the unit file path (Loaded:) so you can see how it is managed by debian, then /etc/logrotate.d should contain a file "apache2" with a decription of how log rotation is handled.

Comment: The failure is _before_ this; the logs clearly state that Apache was not even running when it tried to reload.

Comment: crontab -u root -l to see all cronjobs for root.  Or you may want to check the crontabs for the user running apache2.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ok, so something has gone bad before 06:25:02, but the service apache2 is still running, otherwise there would not be this log entry by apache2[28370]. I just assumed that "service apache2 running" and "Apache2 server running" is the same thing. Is there any log where the server failure would be registered?